# pyqt5 iterate over the items in a stacked widget?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

In this example

```
Stack = QStackedWidget (self)
stack1 = QWidgetA()
stack2 = QWidgetB()
stack3 = QWidgetC()

Stack.addWidget (self.stack1)
Stack.addWidget (self.stack2)
Stack.addWidget (self.stack3)
```

is there any way to iterate over Stack to retrieve the widgets that are the various items in the Stack?

I haven't found a function in QStackedWidget

Ideally I would be able to get back the instances of QWidgetA, QwidgetB, and QwidgetC that are in stack1, stack2, and stack3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the [`QStackedWidget::count()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html#count-prop) of items and iterate from zero to `< count()` using your favorite loop flavor. Each QWidget you added can then be gotten with [`QStackedWidget::widget(index)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html#widget)

Comment: This solves the problem. For those like me, less facile in reading C++ documentation and implementing in pyqt, here are the equivalent lines of code.

    x = Stack.count()
    for i in range(x):
        w = Stack.widget(i)

Comment: @WesR Sorry, yes, I'm a bit C-centric :)  Is there a preferred place for more Python-centric Qt docs? I'd be happy to use that instead for py questions. Cheers!

Comment: @MaximPaperno, seriously, you provided the solution. Thanks! I am gradually learning to translate from Qt C++ to pyqt and I thought I might add a little value here. 

As far as the "best" place for into on pyqt, I find that Stackoverflow with the pyqt tag is the most helpful but if anyone has an alternative I would be happy to know it.

Answer (score 0):

@MaximPaperno' is the solution in c++ speak. I gave it the checkmark. Here is the Python/PyQt code that demonstrates his answer.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

class QWidgetA(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def p(self):
        print('A')

class QWidgetB(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def p(self):
        print('B')

class QWidgetC(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def p(self):
        print('C')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    Stack = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget()
    stack1 = QWidgetA()
    stack2 = QWidgetB()
    stack3 = QWidgetC()

    Stack.addWidget(stack1)
    Stack.addWidget(stack2)
    Stack.addWidget(stack3)

    x = Stack.count()            #<<<<
    for i in range(x):           #<<<<
        w = Stack.widget(i)      #<<<<
        w.p()
```